# Is there a object to object data binding and event framework in javascript/typescript?

Tags: javascript, wpf, typescript, binding

Like this one: https://github.com/errisy/bindable/blob/master/README.md

set up data binding with simple typescript decorators.

Weak Reference in Binding and Event with Path Change Detection.

All the bindings and events are kept as 'weak reference' ITrigger. Once ITrigger.target is set to undefined, the ITrigger will be removed by the caller.

When A.property binds to (or A.method listens to) A.branch.value, if A.branch is changed, the path change can be detected by either the binding host and listener. They will set the ITrigger.target of previous ITrigger to undefined to disable previous binding and listen and then set up new binding and listen to the newly assigned branch.

```
@obs.bindable 
class Person {
    @obs.property
    public Name: string;
    @obs
      .bind(()=>Person.prototyope.Name.FirstName)
      .before(()=>Person.prototype.beforeFirstNameChange)
      .after(()=>Person.prototype.FirstNameChanged)
      .property
    public FirstName: string;
    @obs.event
    public beforeFirstNameChange = () => {
        console.log('before first name is changed.');
    }
    @obs.event
    public FirstNameChanged = () => {
        console.log('first name is changed.');
    }
}
@obs.bindable
class Name{
    @obs.property
    public Surname: string;
    @obs.property
    public FirstName: string;
}

let p = new Person();
p.FirstName = 'Jack'; // p.Name.FirstName will change as well.
```

Comment: While this framework might be nice, this is not the place to advertise it.

Comment: To ask and answer your own question here is fine, however a) the answer needs to be posted as an answer, not part of the question and b) they must conform to the usual quality requirements

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few. My current favorite : https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx which supports *transparent* reactive programming.

## Others

Many non transparent options out there e.g any of the observables like rxjs. Also an old one is knockoutjs but its bound to its own UI programming.